# How to pass javaScript value in view page to Controller Action parameter, when change drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I want to pass student Id in my controller action, I used JsonResult action,  I catch student id but can't pass in action,

this is my JavaScript code ,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sId").change(function(){
            var studentId = $(this).val();
            debugger
            $.ajax({
            type:"post", 
            url:"/Department/GetDeptName/" + studentId,
            contentType:"html",
            success:function(response){
            debugger
            $("#dId").empty();
            $("#did").append(response);
            }
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

And I have a Dropdown list, I pass my list fron database using ViewBag. When I select a student name then need to pass his/her department name. This is  the view code

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">Student Name</label>
                <select asp-for="Id" class="form-control" id="sId"
                        asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.messageStudent,"Id", "Name"))">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                <label asp-for="DeptName" class="control-label">Department Name</label>
                <input asp-for="DeptName" id="dId" class="form-control mb-3"  type="text" placeholder="Dept Name" disabled>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" name="Id" id="DeptName" />

        </div>
```

This is my controller code that is passed a list from database to View

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> DropDown()
    {
        var model = _scope.Resolve<FormModel>();

        await model.LoadStudenDataAsync();
        var studentList = model.StudentList.ToList();

        studentList.Insert(0, new Student { Id = 0, Name = "Select Group" });

        ViewBag.messageStudent = studentList;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now I need to pass student id from view page, if i pass student id then I solve my problem,
This is my JsonResult Action

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetDeptName(int studentId)
    {
        var model = _scope.Resolve<FormModel>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await model.DeptList(studentId);
        }

        return Json(model);
    }
```

Please help me anyone how to pass student id,Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use get ajax since you are not posting any data in the request body. And change data type to json since you are returning json

```
$.ajax({
            type:"GET", 
            url:"/Department/GetDeptName/" + studentId,
            dataType: 'json',
            ....
```

and action

```
[Route("~/Department/GetDeptName/{studentId}")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetDeptName(int studentId)
```

and fix route config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
         {
          routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
          routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
          routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

but if you use old net that doesn't support attribute routing then just change ajax and leave the action as it is now

```
$.ajax({
            type:"GET", 
            url:"/Department/GetDeptName?studentId=" + studentId,
            dataType: 'json',
            ....
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Passed student id in controller, Again lot of thanks